# Using a react native library that requires linking inside my react native library

Tags: reactjs, react-native, module

Is there a way how to use a react native library that requires linking, inside another custom react native library without including it as a peer dependency? so when the custom library is used by a project and linked, all its dependencies that requires linking are linked automatically within the project?

Comment: Would love to know the exact same thing. Did you find an answer?

Comment: @jspizziri In my case I had to flatten it to break the transitive dependency i.e cloning the react native library ios and android code into my library.

Comment: Thanks for responding! Makes sense, but I don't think I want it that badly :).

Comment: Also FWIW I just found this, which makes it seems like there isn't a good way to do it:

https://github.com/callstack/react-native-builder-bob/issues/94

Comment: There's also this https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/27292#issuecomment-699810660